# What data type is expected for the value property of Material UI TimePicker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

[In the documentation](https://mui.com/x/api/date-pickers/time-picker/) it says `any` and I couldn't find anything about what data types are supported. And the value it sends to the onChange function seems to be some sort of object but not a `Date` object and in the typescript code it's just `any`

Answer (score 0):

According to [how it's being used in the documentation](https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/getting-started/), it supports [dayjs](https://day.js.org/) objects and it seems that it works only with such external library